# autocomplete in django with jquery : display two fields in the form suggestion

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have in Django a view with an autocomplete search. In the logic of the script,  I search for city name or I search by zip code. In the select form it works. Is it possible to display both at the same time?

here my form with the jquery :

```
<form  method="GET" action="{% url 'ville_select' name='name' %}" > 
         {% csrf_token %}
               <label for="villeselect">Ville</label>
        <input type="text"  name="name"  id="villeselect" >
        <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>  
$(function () {
            $("#villeselect").autocomplete({
                source: "{% url 'recherche' %}",
                minLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
```

the class for display result in views.py

```
class VilleSelect(ListView):
    model = VilleCountry    
    template_name = 'ville/ville_select.html'    
        
    def get_context_data(self,*arg,**kwargs):
        
        context = super(VilleSelect,self).get_context_data(*arg,**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('name')
        context['posts'] = VilleCountry.objects.filter(Q(name__startswith=query) | Q(zip_code__startswith=query) )   
               
        return context
```

currently i have this

[image]

and what i want

[image]

it is possible to make this.

thank

Answer (score 0):

See if this works,
Try adding `__str__()` function in your VilleCountry model

```
Class VilleCountry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    zip_coide = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "ville_country"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {self.zip_code}"
```

This will ensure that this model will always return both name and zipcode

Comment: I added in my model return f"{self.name} - {self.zip_code}" instead of  return "self.name", unfortunately it does not change anything